# How to make /out directory appears in the project (cannot include it)?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IDEA 12. I cannot include `/out` directory into my project.

I tried `Project Structure -> Modules -> MyModule -> Sources` and then click on `Exclude`, but nothing happens. `/out` directory still remains **excluded** and **red-colored**.

Is this a bug or I am doing it wrongly?

Screenshot

[image]

I can't deselect Exclude to make folder included.

Comment: What is your project structure? Probably one of the parent directories of `out` is excluded

Comment: @Vic Tried with parent /out and all its subfolders, but all in vain. `out` is the first dir in the main root, just like `src`. Can you make this folder visible? IDEA 12?

Comment: Do you have **Exclude output paths** enabled in `Modules` | `Paths`?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Please take a look at the image attached. `out` is read because I cannot deselect it and make it non-excluded.

Comment: Do you have a smaller picture? =) I was asking about `Paths` tab.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Sorry, I over-resized it. Here is another one. Am I suppose to check the 1st red arrow and unchech the 2nd?

Comment: Give it a try. If the issue remains, provide a sample project to reproduce it.

Comment: @CrazyCoder It did not help. I checked `Use module output...` and unchecked `Exclude output path`, clicked OK, closed the project, opened it again, but I still do not see `out` directory. It is no longer red in `Sources`, but it is still **not visible**.

Comment: See also `Settings` | `File Types` | **Ignore files and folders**.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Nothing there either. There are: `CVS;SCCS;RCS;rcs;.DS_Store;.svn;.pyc;.pyo;*.pyc;*.pyo;.git;*.hprof;_svn;.hg;*.lib;*~;__pycache__;.bundle;*.orig;*.rbc;`

Comment: Is that a Maven project? Can you provide a sample to reproduce?

Comment: @CrazyCoder No, Android project. You can try with an empty project. I've just tried. The same scenario occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Android specific bug, I've created a new issue, please vote:

- [IDEA-97776](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97776) Output is excluded from the project view regardless the "excluded folders" and "exclude output paths" settings

Answer (score 3):

'Exclude output paths' option on 'Paths' tab relates to the **module** output path. The **project** output specified in File | Project Structure | Project | 'Project compiler output' is always excluded. If you really need to include it you can do the following:

1. Switch to 'Use module compile output path' option on 'Paths' tab for all modules.
2. Select 'Project' item in the left list and clear 'Project compiler output' field.
3. Reopen the project.

After that 'out' directory should become visible in the 'Project View'. However I recommend you to exclude actual module output subdirectories in the 'Sources' tab by hand. Otherwise IDEA may rescan and reindex output files generated by the compiler after each compilation and this can lead to performance problems.